# Timing individual operations with GNU parallel

Tags: bash, time, parallel-processing, gnu

I would like to keep track of the (1) time for each individual job, and (2) the total time for a complete script. I realize that I could do this in the bash script and just write the indidividual times to a file to look at after the fact, but gnu parallel reports the average time to complete a process so it must keep track already, right?

Is there a straightforward way to maintain that information in a usable format?

Thanks for any tips.  I am new to gnu parallel and am just starting to really appreciate its power!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `--joblog`.

If you are new to GNU Parallel spend an hour walking through the tutorial - you command line will love you for it:
http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html